# PHP array empty outside of function

Tags: php, arrays, function, global-variables, scope

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pid = '129';

$families = array
(
      "Griffin"=>array
                      (
                      "PTY"=>"Peter",
                      "STY"=>"X",
                      "QTY"=>"A|F"
                      ),
      "Quagmire"=>array
                      (
                      "NTY"=>"Glenn"
                      ),
      "Brown"=>array
                  (
                  "FTY"=>"Cleveland",
                  "OTY"=>"Q|G|T|Y",
                  "PTY"=>"Junior"
                  )
);

global $allid;

$allid = array();
function buildid($pid,$key,$val){

    if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
        $val = explode("|",$val);
            foreach($val as $val1){
                $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val1;
                $allid[] = $id;

            }
    }
}

print_r($allid);  

foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){
    foreach($familiesvalue as $skey=>$sval){
        buildid($pid,$skey,$sval);
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Expected output for the above code:**

**Case1:**

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => 129-QTY-A
        [1] => 129-QTY-F
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 129-OTY-Q
        [1] => 129-OTY-G
        [2] => 129-OTY-T
        [3] => 129-OTY-Y
    )
```

**Case2:**

```
 Array
    (
      [0] => 129-QTY-A
      [1] => 129-QTY-F
      [2] => 129-OTY-Q
      [3] => 129-OTY-G
      [4] => 129-OTY-T
      [5] => 129-OTY-Y
    )
```

Comment: using same code with a different logic can also be a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `global $allid;` goes into the function itself, not outside, i.e.

```
   function buildid($pid,$key,$val){
        global $allid;
        if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
    ...
```

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) points out that

> Using `global` keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

--> Unless you do include it from inside a function, it has no effect.

Edit to add: You also need to put the `print_r` after you run the code (i.e. right before `echo '</pre>';`) - currently, you are showing the content of the array right after you initialize it, then you fill it with data, and then your program ends.

Comment: No it's not working. I am getting an emtpy array!

Comment: Just noticed there is an additional issue: You do print_r first, *then* you actually run the code. You need to put your print_r at the *end* of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**First.** You make `print_r($allid)` before setting to this array the data. You did it only in  "`foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){`..."]

**Second.Done.**

**TRY**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pid = '129';

$families = array
(
      "Griffin"=>array
                      (
                      "PTY"=>"Peter",
                      "STY"=>"X",
                      "QTY"=>"A|F"
                      ),
      "Quagmire"=>array
                      (
                      "NTY"=>"Glenn"
                      ),
      "Brown"=>array
                  (
                  "FTY"=>"Cleveland",
                  "OTY"=>"Q|G|T|Y",
                  "PTY"=>"Junior"
                  )
);


function buildid($pid,$key,$val){
 global $allid;
    if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
        $val = explode("|",$val);
            foreach($val as $val1){
                $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val1;
                $allid[] = $id;

            }
    }
}



foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){
    foreach($familiesvalue as $skey=>$sval){
        buildid($pid,$skey,$sval);
    }
}


print_r($allid);
```

Comment: You can re-phrase, your answer is not clear!

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting array before setting its value. So code should be like this.
Your function buildid() is defined but not called before outputting array.
so print_r($allid); should be called afters its value are filled in foreach loop.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pid = '129';

$families = array
(
    "Griffin"=>array
    (
        "PTY"=>"Peter",
        "STY"=>"X",
        "QTY"=>"A|F"
    ),
    "Quagmire"=>array
    (
        "NTY"=>"Glenn"
    ),
    "Brown"=>array
    (
        "FTY"=>"Cleveland",
        "OTY"=>"Q|G|T|Y",
        "PTY"=>"Junior"
    )
);

$allid = array();

function buildid($pid,$key,$val){
     //Global should be inside function like this.
    global $allid;
    if (preg_match("/\|/",$val)){
        $val = explode("|",$val);
        foreach($val as $val1){
            $id = $pid.'-'.$key.'-'.$val1;
            $allid[] = $id;

        }
    }
}

foreach($families as $familieskey=>$familiesvalue){
    foreach($familiesvalue as $skey=>$sval){
        buildid($pid,$skey,$sval);
    }
}
print_r($allid);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: sorry dude! it's already replied by Jan Schejbal